# Gradient colour for a vertical/horizontal line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gradient

I'd like to apply a colour map to a vertical line to be a gradient, depending on it's distance in y. I am using the classic vlines method to plot lines:
`plt.vlines(xVal, 0, maxY, color='C0')`

To create a vertical gradient, I imagine I would use matplotlib's `LineCollection` method, but I cannot figure out how to apply the technique to that of a single line, since `vlines` relies on just the x coordinate and the min/max of the y range.

EDIT:

Found a janky solution for anybody who cares.

```
colorRange = np.arange(0, val, 0.01)
colors = plt.cm.OrRd(np.linspace(0, 1, len(colorRange)))
for i, j in enumerate(colorRange):
   plt.vlines(xPlot[ind], 0, colorRange[i], color=colors[i], zorder=-1*i, linewidth=7)
```

For creating a gradient based on many lines and just using z-ordering. Val is the value you want to reach a max/min of in terms of y.

Comment: Suggest you adapt this example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a set of short lines and give them individual colors:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(222)
curve = np.random.randn(1000).cumsum().cumsum()
plt.plot(curve)
xval = curve.argmax()
ymax = curve.max()
num_pieces = 100
ys = np.linspace(0, ymax, num_pieces + 1)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('turbo')
plt.vlines(np.repeat(xval, num_pieces), ys[:-1], ys[1:], colors=cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, num_pieces)))
plt.show()
```

[image: many short vlines with color]

Comment: Was this answer helpful?